# Foreign key depending on Boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, join

I'm a newbie learning Ruby on Rails and everything else. I'm wondering if Rails has a magic way to implement this:

table 1

```
User table:
id, user_name, fake_id, user_fake_name
```

table 2

```
Post table:
id, fake_or_real, auth_id
```

fake_or_real is a Boolean value; auth_id is a foreign key of user_id or user_fake_id.

if fake_or_real == 1, then auth_id = user_fake_id; auth_name = user_fake_name

if fake_or_real == 0, then auth_id = user_id; auth_name = user_name

The reason I use two id is because I want to hide the user_id in html code when user use fake name in the post. Please let me know if this is not necessary.

What should I do to get jointable works, and make post.auth_name works in both case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there's no way to have foreign-key on one of to fields (and it's db limitation*). What you can do is

Let a `User` have a single `FakeUser` which delegates most of the attributes to `User` (except for id and name)
A `Post` should then have a polimorphic association, let's call it `authorable` on other side of which may be a `User` or `FakeUser`. Voila!

More on polymorphic associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

*limitation is not a good word here, it would be impossible to implement.

Comment: Thanks. Polymorphic association looks like a great feature. I will look deeper into it.